# J1939 Communication over CAN, J1939 Protocol Stack

Tags: matlab, real-time, simulink, can-bus, j1939

I need some guidance on how to use the J1939 library for the Simulink Real-time toolbox.
I am using the previous version which is 6.7 (R2017b). There is very little documentation or example on it.

What I want to achieve is to send a CAN message on the channel 1 and receive it on channel 2.
Can anyone share the steps on how to send a frame, with the setup of the different blocks.

In my model I have considered the blocks:

1. J1939 Database where I added the dbc and it is fine
2. J1939 Controller Application : I just used the General tab. I am not about the Network management tab content, where I have put Arbitrary Address Capable
3. J1939 Protocol Stack: Not sure what I can connect to the inputs or outputs of the block: CAN Msg and N?
4. J1939 Transmit message, I added the frame and it seems ok
5. J1939 Receive message, I also added the same frame and the block seems ok too
6. Setup  block CAN-AC2-PCI B1 FIFO: CAN1 / CAN2 to manage the CAN board which also seem to be OK

At the moment with the way I configured them, I am seeing any frame sent on the bus.

Can anyone share with me how to configure the blocks?

Many thanks for your support.

Comment: I wanted to know how to configure the blocks to be able to send a frame?

Comment: what is you physical setup? Are you not seeing any frames received? Can you check frames sent with an oscilloscope?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.